# Changing classes in jQuery only works the first time I click

Tags: jquery, class

To all the jQuery guru's out there I could use your help pointing out what is probably a silly error on my part. I'm trying to swap classes onclick when the user clicks on a div with the hotspot class. The code below swaps the class the first time I click but not the second and subsequent times. Also if there's a cleaner way to accomplish this please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your expertise.

**jQuery:**

```
$('.hotspot').click(function() {
    if($(this).parent().attr("class") == 'checked'){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('checked').addClass('unchecked');  
    }
    if($(this).parent().attr("class") == 'unchecked'){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('unchecked').addClass('checked');  
    } 
});
```

**Markup:**

```
<ul id="prettyCheck">
    <li class="checked">
          <div class="hotspot"></div>
          <div class="desc"><div class="descPad">Some text</div></div>
    </li>
    <li class="unchecked">
          <div class="hotspot"></div>
          <div class="desc"><div class="descPad">Some text</div></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('.hotspot').toggle(function() {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('checked');
      $(this).parent().addClass('unchecked');
      // do more here...
  }, 
  function(){
      $(this).parent().removeClass('unchecked');
      $(this).parent().addClass('checked');  
      // do more here...
});
```

**or**

```
  $('.hotspot').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('checked');
      $('checkbox selector').attr('checked', $(this).parent().hasClass('checked'));
      // do more here...
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! Definitely getting close, the toggle is working great and I see that I can continue to add as needed, the only hiccup is that when the class is defaulted to unchecked I have to click it twice before the class will toggle. I did try swapping the functions but that only resulted in the same condition when checked is the default.

Comment: Your update is perfect for toggling the classes, am still figuring out how to do the conditional things I need after the toggle, ie. showing/hiding other divs in addition to the checkbox checked you gave me above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without chaning?

```
$('.hotspot').click(function() {
  if($(this).parent().attr("class") == 'checked'){
      $(this).parent().removeClass('checked');
      $(this).parent().addClass('unchecked');
  }
  if($(this).parent().attr("class") == 'unchecked'){
      $(this).parent().removeClass('unchecked');
      $(this).parent().addClass('checked');  
  } 
});
```

Comment: You bet, same result as the chained single line, works the first time but not subsequent times.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that if the class is already checked, then the first `if` statement will uncheck it, then the next `if` will re-check it.  Try changing the second `if` to an `else if` and see if that fixes it for you.  I did that, and also did what sberry2A suggested by replacing `.attr('class') == 'checked'` with `.hasClass('checked')`, and it's working for me.

**Edit:**  And as for why you could only toggle each element once with your original code, it's because the test for `.hasClass('checked')` would only be true if the class name were exactly "checked" (and the same goes for `.hasClass('unchecked')` and the class name "unchecked").  jQuery's `addClass()` function prepends a space to the class that you give it, so that if you tell it to add the class "checked", it will add the string " checked" to the classname.  Because of this, an element starting with the classname "checked" would be modified to have the class name " unchecked", and would no longer match either of your `if` statements, preventing it from toggling any more.  That's why sberry2A suggested using `hasClass()`, since it will return true if the element's classname contains the class that you pass it, even if there's extra space or other classes within the classname.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
In addition to Reigels code I can add ID's to each of my hotspots and use those for other onclick functions to do anything I need.

Thanks for the help!